# How to consume streaming response from SpringBoot service in Angular 4 using observables?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, streaming, observable

I've created a microservice that returns a response in form of a stream using `StreamingResponseBody` class. I want to consume this response in AJAX call using RxJS Observables in my Angular 4 application. Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/oneToHundred", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public StreamingResponseBody oneToHundred() {
        return new StreamingResponseBody() {
            @Override
            public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                for (int i=1;i<=100;i++) {
                    out.write((i + "\n").getBytes());
                    out.flush();
                }

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Needless to say that there will be partial results before the request is entirely completed. I want to update the UI as soon as I'm getting a partial result, say display each partial result in as a list item on my HTML page like follows:

- 1
- 2...

after next set of partial response

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4...

after next set of partial response

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 9......

upto

- ...
- 98
- 99
- 100

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: I did actually, using fetch and ReadableStream.getReader().

refer to 
1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream

and 

2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader

upon receiving each bundle of data from the back-end, we can handle them individually.


It can be used in a variety of ways to improve site performance.